# Lync 2010 change display name of sender

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2010, lync-client-sdk, lync-2013

Does anyone know how to override the display name of the sender of an instant message using the Microsoft.Lync API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using [`Conversation.Impersonate(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/hh384421.aspx), which contains the following option:

> ***displayName***
>
> > Type: System.String
> >     The display name of the user to impersonate. Optional.

However, when I tried it, setting the displayname changed nothing. I ended up just setting the `uri` property to `someusername@example.org` to show the username. It looks like the Lync client only displays usernames for known users.